# Central place for RabbitMQ queue binding management in a microservice-based app

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, message-queue, spring-amqp, rabbitmq-exchange

I'm working on a microservice-based application. It is built of ca. 30 microservices and as usually some of them communicate with each other over **RabbitMQ**.

Such services have names of exchanges, queues and routing keys in their configuration file (`application.yml`).
All the corresponding beans (bindings included) are created in a `@Configuration`.
All of them are created automatically on service startup.

As it's a startup project it's characterized by lots of changes in design, renaming of exchanges, routing keys, queues etc.

Therefore it would be great to have a central place where all the necessary bindings could be managed.
So you would have to rename an exchange and/or routing key in one place.
The other advantage is transparency - one text file contains information about what services depend on what exchanges.

The configuration of such a management component could look like:

```
services:
    service1: s1
        binding1:
            exchange: e1
            queue1: s1q1
            routing-key: rk1
        binding2:
            exchange: e1
            queue1: s1q2
            routing-key: rk2
        ...
    service2: s2
        binding1:
            exchange: e2
            queue1: s2q1
            routing-key: rk3
        binding2:
            exchange: e2
            queue1: s2q1
            routing-key: rk4
        ...
    ...
```

And the configuration of `service1` could just contain queue names:

```
config:
    queue1: s1q1
    queue2: s1q2
...
```

The services would create queues only and the management component - exchanges and bindings.

I'm thinking about creating additional service whose only purpose would be the creation of the bindings.
However I'm not sure whether I wouldn't reinvent the wheel.

Is there such a utility (maybe RabbitMQ plugin) that solves this?

Comment: Have you looked at spring-clound-config for centralizing your configuration? https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-config

Comment: @GaryRussell Doesn't it just hold the configuration? But I want to move exchange/binding creation out of the services. They should only know what queues to create and how. However queue creation can possibly be delegated either.

Answer (score 0):

This is a first rate example of governance applied to an EDA. It avoids ungoverned spaghetti routing. A service should simply be fed messages into an input queue for that service only and then raise it's processed events to it's dedicated output queue. The routing of its events from its private output queue, publicly around the enterprise, is not the concern of the individual service and should not be influenced by it. That should be controlled separately and centrally, in a declarative file - a kind of EDA global orchestration mission control (EventOrchestration.yml). This config is then read by a release automation script for configuring the routing of the message broker.
I am new to RabbitMQ and would also like an answer - just started reading up today. It can be done with Azure service bus, with forwarding and filtering rules. Forwarding rules route an event based on the header or payload attributes of the msg. But looks like a similar thing exists in RabbitMQ, by setting the routing rules at the exchange-level based on a routing key in the message.